# POSTアクセスを相対パスではなく絶対パスで行いたい

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://www.example.com/
というサイトで

https://www.example.com/blog/
というページがあったとして

以下のようにjQueryでPOSTアクセスを投げると

```
function test()
{
    $.post('/aaa',{},
    (data) => {

    });
}
```

https://www.example.com/blog/aaa
に対してのPOSTアクセス(?)になりますが

https://www.example.com/blog/edit
というページから
同じtest()関数を使ってPOSTアクセスを投げると

https://www.example.com/blog/edit/aaa
に対してのPOSTになってしまいます。

関数を使いまわしたいので、同じURLに対してPOSTを投げたいのですが
どのような処理にするのが良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そもそも質問文が間違っていて`aaa`を指定した場合についてでしょうか、その場合
https://www.example.com/blog/ → https://www.example.com/blog/aaa
https://www.example.com/blog/edit → https://www.example.com/blog/edit/aaa
と意図しないアドレスに移動します。

質問文通り`/aaa`を指定した場合
https://www.example.com/blog/ → https://www.example.com/aaa
https://www.example.com/blog/edit → https://www.example.com/aaa
となります。

つまりあと一歩足りなかっただけであり、結論としては`/blog/aaa`を指定すると期待通りの動作になります。
https://www.example.com/blog/ → https://www.example.com/blog/aaa
https://www.example.com/blog/edit → https://www.example.com/blog/aaa